# Drush command 'omega-wizard' could not be found

Tags: drush, theming

I want to create a sub-theme with Omega using drush but I get a couple of errors.  I've been trying to solve these problems for a bit now and I need some help.  I'm using OS X and XAMPP as my local web server.

When I change directories into my site:

`/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/joshvocal/sites/all/themes`

and run `drush omega-wizard` I get these errors:

`The drush command 'omega-wizard' could not be found.  Run drush cache-clear drush to clear the commandfile cache if you[error]have installed new extensions.
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.

Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See
drush topic docs-aliases for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.`

I think the problem has something with drush not being able to connect to my database.

I've tried:

- Changing my settings.php file from `host: localhost` to `host: 127.0.0.1`
- Creating a symbolic link with `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql.sock`

When I run my `drush status` this is what is looks like:

[image: My drush status]

I think this is what it should somewhat look like:

[image: What I think drush status should look like]

I want to know how to fix these errors and be able to run `drush omega-wizard` to create a sub-theme on omega.

Thank you for your time,

Josh

Comment: Is the site accessible? After downloading the omega theme have you cleared your cache? Also try doing "drush owiz" to start creating your subtheme.

Comment: Yes, the site is accessible through localhost on my computer.  I've tried clearing the cache with `drush cc drush` and `drush cc`.  I also cleared the cache on the website in performance, it didn't work. `drush owiz`gives me the same errors as the first picture above.

Comment: Since at the moment you're using Drupal 7, could you try using Drush 6? You're using composer to install Drush?

Comment: I could try using Drupal 6, but I prefer moving forward and using the most current stable version.  Yeah, I'm using composer to install Drush.  I've followed these youtube tutorials: [How To Install Drush on OSX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3-OlfI3bAI) and [Installing Drush on Mac OS X with Composer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQNzl4XZtcc)

Comment: I understand too but I just want to narrow down the possibilities of error then we could move to other possible causes maybe? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I can use other commands like `drush dl omega` and that works.  I think the problem is that drush isn't properly connect to my local database.

Comment: I suspect that too since you're able to do drush cc, could you try to restart apache and mysql please?

Comment: I've restarted Apache Web Server, mySQL Database and the  application to run them.  I still get the same errors.

Comment: Based on from http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ try running `composer self-update` and/or `composer update`

Comment: Also you could check this out https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1188

Comment: You shouldn't be running drush from that directory, you should be running it from an alias or in sites/default or sites/sitename (wherever the settings file is actually located), have you tried this? To get a proper bootstrap of Drupal which the screenshot doesn't have this is probably the issue.

Comment: I tried running from the directory where the settings.php file is located and I still get the errors.   How would I connect or get a proper bootstrap of Drupal and connect it?

Answer (score 3):

Add `-d` option so that command looks `drush -d omega-wizard`. You will see debugging information showing what causes problems.

Comment: great it works for me thank but i can not understand why we use -d before omega-wizard Please justify thank you in advance

Comment: This really should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: and the -d flag adds debugging output.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, turns out I didn't have the MySQL bin directory in my system path.

This question appears quite high up Google, so for anyone else reading this having the same issue...

Go to `Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables`, double click on `Path` under `System variables`, click `New` and add the path to your MySQL bin directory.

In my case this was `H:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.11\bin`, but it will depend on the location of your WAMP installation.